# How to get post-receive server hook to run

Tags: git, gitlab

I’ve just installed a fresh version of GitLab on my own server:

```
{“version”:“15.3.3-ee”,“revision”:“1615d086ad8”}
```

System information:

```
System:         Debian 11
Proxy:          no
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.7.5p203
Gem Version:    3.1.6
Bundler Version:2.3.15
Rake Version:   13.0.6
Redis Version:  6.2.7
Sidekiq Version:6.4.0
```

I tried to follow this guide to set up a post-receive hook : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html

I confirmed the location of the Git repo via console and made the custom_hooks folder

```
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/4a/44# ls -l
total 12
drwx--S--- 5 git git 4096 Sep  7 14:40 4a44dc15364204a80fe80e9039455cc1608281820fe2b24f1e5233ade6af1dd5.git
drwx--S--- 4 git git 4096 Sep  7 14:09 4a44dc15364204a80fe80e9039455cc1608281820fe2b24f1e5233ade6af1dd5.wiki.git
drwxr-sr-x 2 git git 4096 Sep  7 14:38 custom_hooks
```

Created the file with proper owner. I tried multiple permissions settings.

```
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/4a/44# cd custom_hooks/
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/4a/44/custom_hooks# ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 git git 43 Sep  7 14:34 post-receive
```

The file is a simple test script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test custom" > /tmp/hook
```

which runs properly when manually run as git user

```
git@gitlab:~/git-data/repositories/@hashed/4a/44/custom_hooks$ ./post-receive
git@gitlab:~/git-data/repositories/@hashed/4a/44/custom_hooks$ cd /tmp/
git@gitlab:/tmp$ ls -l
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 git  git    12 Sep  7 14:46 hook
```

However I can’t get it to run on a push from local to remote (GitLab) repo. The repo files do update properly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that is not correct location for the custom_hooks folder.  It has to go inside the *.git folder.